# How check action bar is visible?

Tags: java, android

I have to check on my activity the action bar is visible or not.
I want to know if you have to pick this property bar action.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check value of

```
getActionBar().isShowing()
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#isShowing()